# Determine if an index is reversed in OracleDB

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, oracle11g, flyway

I am trying to determine if there is a way in Oracle 11g to find out if an index is reversed.  I looked through the documentation for [`ALL_INDEXES`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1069.htm#i1578369)* however I didn't see anything in that table that would indicate that the index is reversed or not.

The reasoning behind this is that we reversed an index to fix an issue with IO Wait in our production environment.  We use flyway for schema migrations to sync our environments and all scripts must be idempotent.  However, I'm not able to find a way to determine if the index in question is reversed on not in order to conditionally rebuild it as reversed.

Is there a way to determine if an index in Oracle DB is reversed using built-in meta tables/views?

* Additional info:

- I won't actually have access to the `ALL_INDEXES` table when this would be run, only `USER_INDEXES` since this will not be executed with DBA permissions.
- The index in question is the primary key of a table if that makes a difference in querying the schema metadata

Comment: You don't need DBA permissions to access `ALL_INDEXES` (only to access `DBA_INDEXES`) - but it doesn't really matter as the information is also available in USER_INDEXES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column `ALL_INDEXES.INDEX_TYPE` will contain the type of the index. For a reverse index this will be `NORMAL/REV` or `FUNCTION-BASED NORMAL/REV`.

This will be the same for `USER_INDEXES`

- [ALL_INDEXES in the Oracle 11 manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_1109.htm#REFRN20088)
- [ALL_INDEXES in the Oracle 12 manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/ALL_INDEXES.html#GUID-E39825BA-70AC-45D8-AF30-C7FF561373B6)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It probably would have helped if I was looking at the documentation for the correct version of Oracle DB.  I was looking at the docs to 10g, which is what I linked, where that wasn't an option.  Thanks for pointing me back in the right direction!